# Reported speech (back shifting of tense)

Tags: tense, backshifting, reported-speech

Suppose, today I tell you a story which happened few days ago and I say that "A few days back I met my dream girl at the shopping mall. But when I asked her name she said that she 'is' busy".

I have two questions regarding this phrase.

Question 1 : 
Here, if at the time of reporting I don't know if she's still busy or not and even then I use 'is', would it be grammatically correct then ?

Question 2 :
You see, even if at the time of telling you the story, she is not still busy and I still use 'is', I don't think it would be wrong because I have already put 'said' which is in the past tense, so obviously the listener would understand she was busy when she spoke to me. Isn't it ?

Thank You.

Comment: It would still be "was" whether she's still be or not.

Comment: If she told you several days ago, "I'm busy", and you want to tell someone in indirect speech, "She told me she was busy" would be the natural choice. If you somehow know that she is not busy now or you're not sure about her status, the natural choice would still be the same, "She told me she was busy". If you somehow know that she still is busy (with a long-running project, for example), a natural choice would be "She told me she was busy, and she still is."

Comment: By the way, if you asked her her name, and she said "I'm busy", "I'm busy" wasn't really used to give you any information about her life, it was only used as a quick rejection or refusal. She may or may not be really busy.

Comment: @Damkerng : I understand that 'iam busy' is not really a reply to give any info about her life but I was interested in asking when is the present tense retained in reported speech ? I come across many such sentences where people do retain the present tense in reported speech and I have repeatedly asked questions over this matter on this forum and surprisingly I've got some mixed replies.

Comment: @Damkerng : Some of them have said that 'She said that she is busy' is grammatically acceptable even if at the time of reporting she is not still busy ? I seek your advise on this question. Thanks

Comment: You said that you've come across many of such sentences. Be careful, one word can change the whole sense of the sentence. Let's focus on this utterance "I'm busy". When you hear it with "is" (i.e. [she said she is busy]), you have to be careful with several points. The most important ones are the context; was it in speech or written?; who said it, a native or non-native speaker, of what dialect?; how did they say it, as direct or indirect speech?; when did they say it, right after she said it or several days later?; and so on.

Comment: @Dankerng : Thanks for your reply. I have already mentioned the context to you.  So under that very context if someone says "She said that she is busy" will it be correct to use 'is' ? Will that be correct in written form or in speech ? The above sentence is clearly a form of indirect speech. So, is it correct to use 'is' in indirect speech form under the context mentioned in the original question ? One more query, some say that 'said' is already in the past tense so even if anyone uses 'is' the listener would understand the meaning, so my question is why use 'is' then ?

Comment: @iamRR One main difference between the spoken and written English is that in spoken English we don't see punctuation marks, so it's fair to doubt your understanding; in other words, are you sure that you heard indirect speech? -- In the "one more query" part, I suspect that you're confused by some other possible cases, which is not the same as in your context (which, according to your question, happened **a** few days ago, but it's unclear how you would convey your 'is' in your speech, or whether it was you who said it or you heard someone else said it).

Comment: @Damkerng : Let me reiterate the context once again. A few days back I met a girl and when I asked her name she said 'I am busy'. Now today I happen to report this story to you and if I say "A few days back I met a girl and when I asked her name she said that she is busy". I don't think there is misunderstanding of punctuation in reported speech. I'm merely asking  if anyone uses 'is' in the indirect speech (just like I used) in the above given contex then will it be grammatically correct ?

Comment: @Damkerng : If its not grammatically correct then why do I often come across such sentence where present tense is retained in indirect speech even if the reported words are not still true?

Comment: If a) a native English speaker said that, b) you did not mistake direct speech for indirect speech, c) the speaker did not make a mistake, d) the word "busy" was used in the way you describe (i.e., it wasn't about any long-running project), and e) it happened several days ago, I think the chance that the utterance you are trying to claim that you "often" come across really happens is slim to none.

Comment: @Damkerng T : So it means that usage of 'is' is grammatically incorrect in the cases a) to e). Is that what you saying ?

Comment: I simply said that I think it's extremely unlikely. (If it really did happen, I'd be very surprised.) -- Please note that I've had no intention to answer this question since in the beginning. One reason is that I believe there are many others who can write a better answer than mine. Another was that your description and claims didn't sound quite right to me. So I tried to help by posting some hints I thought useful as a comment. As it turned out, it wasn't as helpful as I had hoped. This has become a long thread of comments, which I didn't want to happen. I hope you'll get a good answer soon.

Comment: @Damkerng T : Thanks for your constant help. I really appreciate it. You see, I asked this question yesterday and since then I haven't got any answer to it. Could you recommend this question to the person who you feel fits to answer it. Please. I'm too confused.